# If 1 gram force on Earth is 0.0098 N, what would it be on Mars or others?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, si-units, weight

I know that this is a very simple question, but I am not really sure about this. If 1 gram force on Earth is $0.001 \;\text{kg} \times 9.8 \;\text{m}\,\text{s}^{-2}$, what would it be on Mars or any other place? Would it be different or the same?

Comment: The $9.8 \, \mathrm{m/s^2}$ is the gravitational acceleration $g$ on Earth's surface. If you Google it for other planets, you can calculate the values. For instance, the moon's gravity is six times weaker causing $g=1.6\,\mathrm{m/s^2}$.

Comment: https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/ gives the gravitational acceleration at the surface of each of the planets in the Solar System (and the Moon and Pluto).

Comment: So the conclusion is 1 gram force varies from place to place. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. One gram is one gram. The mass is constant. But $g$ varies. And so, the gravitational force varies.

Comment: If you want to be really accurate, Force is measured in Newtons, and only mass is measured in grams. The _weight_ of a one gram mass near the surface of the Earth varies a little bit from place to place, but on average, it is 9.8 millinewtons. 1.6 millinewtons on the Moon, 3.7 millinewtons on Mars, etc.

Comment: Are you asking how much a 1 g mass would weigh on the surface of Mars?

Comment: @David White no. There is this obsolete unit of force called 1 gram force. I am asking if it would be same everywhere.

Comment: @MarkA.Bromuela It's the same everywhere in the universe. It, along with the related kilogram-force (aka kilopond)  are sometimes useful units on the surface of the Earth, particularly in engineering where four places of decimal precision can be high precision. User notovny provided the correct answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It does not change.

A [gram force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilogram-force) is a unit of force *defined* as the force that gives a mass of one gram acceleration of one [standard gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravity) ($9.80665 \, \mathrm{m/s^2}$).

It is not specifically the weight of a gram of mass at a specific location. A gram-force is still a gram-force on Mars, or in interstellar space, or on the surface of a neutron star. The amount of force that the unit represents remains the same.